# How do I validate if my model attribute does NOT match a regex?

Tags: validation, model, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm using Rails 5.  How do I create a validation rule for my model that validset if the attribute does NOT match a pattern?  I have this

```
validates_numericality_of :my_str, :with => /\d:\d/, :allow_blank = true
```

But what I really want to say is validate if the string does not match the regular expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I have understood is that you want the validation to pass if it's not a number so why dont you change the regex to match anything but numbers:

```
/^(?!\d)/
```

Using your code it would be

```
validates_format_of :my_str, :with => /^(?!\d)/, :allow_blank = true
```

Or: 
as the [documentation](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html) says

> Alternatively, you can require that the specified attribute does not
>   match the regular expression by using the :without option.

So:

```
validates_format_of :my_str,format: { without => /\d:\d/},  allow_blank = true
```

with `validates_format_of` validates the attributes' values by testing whether they match a given regular expression, which is specified using the `:with` or `:without` options

Comment: Does ":without" exist in Rails 5 (Ruby 2.4)?  I created "validates :my_num, numericality: { greater_than: 0, :only_integer => true }, :allow_blank => true, :without => /\d:\d/" but am getting the error, "/Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activemodel-5.0.2/lib/active_model/validations/validates.rb:120:in `rescue in block in validates': Unknown validator: 'WithoutValidator' (ArgumentError)"

Comment: use `validates_format_of ` instead of `validates_numericality_of`, which has `:without` option.